# Angular forms - How to bind formControlName for select in formArrayName to use objects

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a binding object complex binding for `select` inside formArrayName. I'm guessing that formControlName should have reference to the current item in the array, but I don't know how to access it.

```
<div formArrayName="users">
    <div *ngFor="let u of users.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]='i'>
      user {{i}}: <select formControlName='id'[compareWith]="compareFn">
        <option *ngFor="let a of avaliableUsers" [ngValue]='a'>{{a.login}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've created demo with single select (which is working as I want) and array which is pushing value into "id".
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2uaa1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Key points:

- Bind the whole `UsersGroup` objects with all properties (id and login)
- Minimum additional code (KISS)

**Solution** (Based on @JT_82 comment)

```
   <div *ngFor="let u of users.controls; let i=index">
      <select [formControlName]='i' [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <option *ngFor="let a of avaliableUsers" [ngValue]='a'>{{a.login}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.owner.patchValue(this.group.owner);
    this.group.users.forEach(u => {
      this.users.push(this.fb.control(u))
    });
  }

 compareFn(a, b): boolean {
    return a.id === b.id;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Per OP's wishes, we would like to keep the object as value in the select, for that we can instead of using a formgroup inside the formarray, just push formcontrols, which then contains object values:

```ts
this.group.users.forEach(u => {
  this.users.push(this.fb.control(u)) // just push formcontrol!
});
```

and then mark in template:

```html
<select [formControlName]='i' [compareWith]="compareFn">
  <option *ngFor="let a of avaliableUsers" [ngValue]='a'>{{a.login}}</option>
</select>
```

Since we are now using an object value as the formcontrol, when trying to match preset values, we need a compareWith function:

```ts
compareFn(a, b): boolean {
  return a.id === b.id;
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh3xyg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I would perhaps call a function when the select changes, and then find the user from `availableUsers` and set the form value for `login` with the found user. So template:

```html
<select formControlName='id' (change)="findLogin(u)">
  <option *ngFor="let a of avaliableUsers" [ngValue]='a.id'>{{a.login}}</option>
</select>
```

So you can remove `compareWith`, since we are now using a number for the value. Then the `findLogin` function where we pass the current formgroup from the iteration:

```ts
findLogin(group: FormGroup) {
  const user = this.avaliableUsers.find(x => x.id === group.get('id').value)
  group.get('login').setValue(user.login);
}
```

Your forked **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnhnhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but I would like to archive this without copying data in on change event. Not that if you setup ngValue="a" you already have the whole object in the `option` and I would like to reuse it. In my application, I need to support a quite complex user model and I would like to remove all future maintenance at the beginning and have "stupid simple solution" for this.

Comment: @igby Well, one option I then see, is not to push formgroups to your array, but form controls (which is then an object). Then you need a `compareWith` function. Here's that option: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh3xyg?file=src/app/app.component.ts Depending on case, maybe this could work for you?

Comment: YES! This I was searching exact such setup. I even understand my mistake :D
Big Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it was suitable for you! Updated answer to also reflect that option for future readers :)